# Should the periodic table's groups be hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

The elements of the periodic table are arranged in columns or groups. This way, carbon belongs to group IV, whereas nitrogen is in group V.

If these group names are used as adjectives, should they be hyphenated or is hyphenation optional? For example, which should I use:

> Different group-IV materials can be used in microelectronics.

or

> Different group IV materials can be used in microelectronics.

I have seen both ways in different scientific papers.

Comment: Outside of any science-specific jargon, the normal way of describing the group that's numbered "IV" would be Group IV.  But in this context, you're not describing the fourth group (which is what Group IV sounds like), you're describing the things that are grouped together because they have the quality *IV*.  In that case, IV Group could also work.

Comment: @Juhasz I do not understand your comment. By "group IV materials"/"group-IV materials" (whatever option is correct), I mean "materials that belong to the group IV".

Comment: "The group IV" is not good English.  We would typically call a group "Group IV."  If you wanted to describe materials in Group IV, you would write "Group IV materials" - just as you would write "General Motors employees", not "General-Motors employees", or "Amazon Prime membership", not "Amazon-Prime membership."

Comment: @Juhasz, "The" in this case does not refer to "group IV" but to "materials," and Group IV is a modifier.

Comment: Example: I can say "The apples are ripe" or be more specific and say "The red-colored apples are ripe."

Comment: @barbecue, you're right that in the phrase "the group IV materials" *the* belongs to *materials*.  But the original post and a comment both use the phrase "belong to the group IV."  That's what I'm commenting on.

Comment: @Juhasz yep, sorry, I misread your comment.

Comment: @Juhasz You mean I should say “Carbon belongs to Group IV,” with “Group” capitalized? If so, I understand I should say “Different Group IV materials can be used in microelectronics.” However I have read many (most?) publications in which “group” is written lowercase, as if it weren’t a proper noun.

Comment: @baister in my experience "group" in this usage is generally only capitalized when it's the first word of a sentence, or when it's in a title or caption where title case is normally used.

Comment: @barbecue In such a case I don't see why I should say "Different group IV materials..." instead of the hyphenated version.

Comment: @barbecue I mean, in a previous comment "Group IV" was compared to "Amazon Prime" or "General Motors". If "Group IV" is the proper noun that defines those elements that share a specific characteristic, I understand that I could say something like "Group IV materials are those which belong to the periodic table's group Group IV." However, if "Group IV" is not a proper noun, then "group" is a common noun and "IV" is an adjective that modifies it, so that I find "group-IV," and not "group IV," to be a phrasal adjective as you indicated in your answer.

Comment: Generally a proper noun refers to a unique or specific instance of a thing. Amazon Prime is a single specific service, there's no need to distinguish which specific Amazon prime you're referring to. You can argue that group IV is a common noun, specifying one of several possible groups, or you could argue that Group IV is the proper name of the 4th group of elements. This is a pretty specialized situation, but the consensus seems to be that it's not a proper noun.

Comment: @barbecue Thanks. I get your point. If we argue that "group IV" is a common name, would not be reasonable to say "Different group-IV materials..." instead of "Different group IV materials...," just like you suggested in your answer to this question?

Comment: Yep, that's what I am saying.

Comment: @barbecue Thanks. It seems there is no general consensus according to what the other commenter said...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, I would consider group-IV to be a phrasal adjective, or compound modifier, and therefore use a hyphen, as recommended by [many](https://grammarist.com/grammar/phrasal-adjectives/) [popular](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch05/ch05_sec091.html) [style guides](https://style.mla.org/hyphens-and-en-dashes/).

When two words together serve as a modifier for another word, many style manuals recommend hyphenating them, as for example...

> The built-up area of town...
>
> A brightly-lit hallway...

Since this is related to chemistry, I checked the [American Chemical Society's style manual](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch010), which does not specifically address phrasal adjectives, but does favor hyphenation for most modifiers.

However, if you're writing for a specific journal or publication, you may want to ask them what style guide they recommend.